# looks like the dimension x-axis and y-axis is a bit off

Tags: pgfplots, axis, scale

Why is the scale not the same at x-axis and y-axis, looks like the y is a litte bit smaller.

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark,patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
            funk(\x)=10^(\x);
        }]
        % let both axes use the same layers
        \pgfplotsset{set layers}        
        \begin{axis}[                                       
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            xtick={-4,-2,...,14},
            ytick={-4,-2,...,14},
            xmin=-4,xmax=14,ymin=-4,ymax=14, 
            every inner x axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            every inner y axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
            grid=both,minor tick num=1              
            ]       
            
            
            
            
            %Graf for fuktionen
        
            \draw (13,1.9) node [scale=0.7,yshift=-0.25ex] {$f(x)$};
            
            \addplot[smooth,thick,samples=1000, domain=-1:14, blue,y filter/.expression={y<-2?\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:y}] {log10(x)};   
            
            \addplot[smooth,thick,samples=100, domain=-10:2, blue] {10^(x)};    
            
            \addplot[dashed,thick,samples=100, domain=-10:14, black] {x};   
            
            %Punkter    
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (1,0) circle (1.2pt);
        
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (0,1) circle (1.2pt);
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (10,1) circle (1.2pt);
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (1,10) circle (1.2pt);
            
            %Linjer
            
            \draw[dashed,thick,black] (1,10) -- (10,1); 
            
            
        \end{axis}  
        
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Picture of it
[image]

When I ues axis equal I get this picture

[image]

Comment: Looks better with `axis equal,` added to the options list. You might also want to look at `unbounded coords=jump,`

Comment: But how do I get it to show only from -4 to 14?? @daleif

Comment: Erh, you already do? I do not understand the question

Comment: When I write, axis equal I get the picture you see up in the question.

Comment: and then what is your question?

Comment: The lines both x-axis and gridlines outside -4 and 14 I would like not to be there. Og I looks like the picture on top med woth the dimensions in the last picture.

Comment: @JakobKruse Are you looking for `axis equal image=true`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz this solved my problem, thank you.
Can I ask you a small question, is it possible to make grid form -5 to 5 ant then only have the axis to go from -5 to 4?

Comment: @JakobKruse If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.

Comment: okay thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `axis equal image=true` instead of `axis equal`. To quote the pgfplots documentation:

> Similar to `axis equal`, but the axis limits will stay constant as well

---

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark,patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
            funk(\x)=10^(\x);
        }]
        % let both axes use the same layers
        \pgfplotsset{set layers}        
        \begin{axis}[                                       
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            xtick={-4,-2,...,14},
            ytick={-4,-2,...,14},
            xmin=-4,xmax=14,ymin=-4,ymax=14, 
            every inner x axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            every inner y axis line/.append style={-triangle 45},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny,xshift=0.5ex},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny,yshift=0.5ex},
            grid=both,minor tick num=1,
            axis equal image=true              
            ]       
            
            
            
            
            %Graf for fuktionen
        
            \draw (13,1.9) node [scale=0.7,yshift=-0.25ex] {$f(x)$};
            
            \addplot[smooth,thick,samples=1000, domain=-1:14, blue,y filter/.expression={y<-2?\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:y}] {log10(x)};   
            
            \addplot[smooth,thick,samples=100, domain=-10:2, blue] {10^(x)};    
            
            \addplot[dashed,thick,samples=100, domain=-10:14, black] {x};   
            
            %Punkter    
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (1,0) circle (1.2pt);
        
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (0,1) circle (1.2pt);
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (10,1) circle (1.2pt);
            
            \draw[line width=1pt, color=black,fill=black] (1,10) circle (1.2pt);
            
            %Linjer
            
            \draw[dashed,thick,black] (1,10) -- (10,1); 
            
            
        \end{axis}  
        
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]